# ChartJS, nested flexbox, not shrinking

Tags: css, flexbox, chart.js

I have a ChartJS canvas object that is shrinking when it is in a single flexbox, but not shrinking when it is in a nested flexbox and looking for some advice on how to handle this; e.g. by simple CSS, by handling an onresize event and modifying the canvas element. I think it first start by understanding the root cause of this behavior.

I tend to believe the issue is related to the responsive limitations of the canvas element, but if that it the case it should also happen with a single flexbox element, right?

- I attached a repro. Note: the resizing works if I only keep the .column flexbox, and it fails when the .column flexbox is nested in the .row flexbox.
- How to reproduce: open the browser window in a smaller than maximized size. Then resize the window to maximum, then resize back to a smaller size. The Chart is not resized back.
- I also tried putting a min-width:1px and min-height:1px on the .chart class, but in this case it only shrinks width and not height (weird!)

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
          data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      animation : false,
      responsive : true,
      maintainAspectRatio : false,
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
      }
    }
});
```

```css
html,body{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
.row{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    height:100%;
}
.fields, .info{
    flex:0 0 250px; 
}
.chart{
    flex:1 1 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
    .column{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        height:100%;
    }
    .head{
        flex:0 1 40px;  
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .main{
        flex:1 1 auto;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .foot{
        flex:0 1 40px;
        border:1px solid black;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="fields">fields</div>
    <div class="chart">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="head">head</div>
            <div class="main"><canvas id="bar-chart"></canvas></div>
            <div class="foot">foot</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">info</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it myself. Apparently applying auto as a flex item starting width is the root cause.

By changing this

```
.main{
    flex:1 1 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

To

```
.main{
   flex:1 1 1px;
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

And let the flex-grow property do the rest (because we said the flex item can grow and shrink and should start with 1px) it will solve the issue.